# How to use android.speech for audio output and mode continuous

Tags: android-studio, audio, input, output

I starting with Android studio, I try to use the class **android.speech** with the selection of the input audio streams, normally it is **the microphone which is used by default**, and I want to use either the microphone or the output sound choice . This is to send the sound of a phone call for example in the class android.speech entry for reading ( because I am deaf ) .

Also, I do not see how to make the class android.speech not stop, that is to say to ensure that the listening **is permanante and continuous**.

I start the application the morning 8H 12H and I talk it should work.

How to remove the START_STT button.

Can you showed me an example of STT in continuous mode, and how chosir the audio input? in github

Two easy questions for complex answers.

If this is possible then I just answer the phone being deaf ..

Best Regards